# Rails how to have models hit a different database dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

Looking to see if it's possible to have a Rails app hit multiple dbs dynamically. To be more precise:

- I have an app that can operate in different regions.
- Each request that comes in will identify the region.
- In mysql, one region corresponds to exactly one db.
- The dbs are identical in terms of the schema. Implying the AR models are all the same, it's just that depending on the request, I want the model object to be retrieved/updated from one of the per region dbs.
- All of the data is isolated to that particular db. There is never any crossover, nor any need to query multiple dbs at the same time.

One way to avoid multiple db's is to add a "region" column to all the models/tables (don't really like that).

Another way to do this would simply be to fire up different instances for different regions. Again, don't really want to do that given all the config overhead (cloud servers, nginx, etc, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Rails 6.1 introduced the notion of horizontal sharding. That was what I needed. And I found this article useful:

https://www.freshworks.com/horizontal-sharding-in-a-multi-tenant-app-with-rails-61-blog/